# How to check whether a line starts with a word or tab or white space in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

can some one tell me how can i check whether a line starts with string or space or tab? I tried this, but not working..

```
if line.startswith(\s):
    outFile.write(line);
```

below is the samp data..

```
female 752.9
    external 752.40
        specified type NEC 752.49
    internal NEC 752.9
male (external and internal) 752.9
    epispadias 752.62"
    hidden penis 752.65
    hydrocele, congenital 778.6
    hypospadias 752.61"*
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

To check a line starts with space or tab.

```
if re.match(r'\s', line):
```

`\s` matches newline character also.

OR

```
if re.match(r'[ \t]', line):
```

To check a line whether it starts with a word character or not.

```
if re.match(r'\w', line):
```

To check a line whether it starts with a non-space character or not.

```
if re.match(r'\S', line):
```

**Example:**

```
>>> re.match(r'[ \t]', '  foo')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 1), match=' '>
>>> re.match(r'[ \t]', 'foo')
>>> re.match(r'\w', 'foo')
<_sre.SRE_Match object; span=(0, 1), match='f'>
>>>
```

Comment: `^` is redundant in `re.match`

Comment: yep, but some people may downvote because of not using anchor.. lol//

Comment: Hi Avinash, thanks.. is there anyway I can get the output as below.. I need to append the subheadings to the below data..          sample: female 752.9
    external 752.40
        specified type NEC 752.49
    internal NEC 752.9   

the final output should be 

female 752.9
female external 752.40
female external specified type NEC 752.49

Comment: What do you mean by subheadings? if you still have any doubts then ask it as a new question. So that you could explain better with an example. OR create a chat room and ping me from that.

Answer (score 13):

To check if a line starts with a space or a tab, you can pass a tuple to `.startswith`.  It will return `True` if the string starts with any element in the tuple:

```
if line.startswith((' ', '\t')):
  print('Leading Whitespace!')
else:
  print('No Leading Whitespace')
```

e.g:

```
>>> ' foo'.startswith((' ', '\t'))
True
>>> '   foo'.startswith((' ', '\t'))
True
>>> 'foo'.startswith((' ', '\t'))
False
```

Comment: Pavan: Note that "startswith" doesn't accept regular expressions or special escapes, just actual characters, which must be in quotes.

Answer (score 5):

```
from string import whitespace

def wspace(string):
    first_character = string[0]  # Get the first character in the line.
    return True if first_character in whitespace else False

line1 = '\nSpam!'
line2 = '\tSpam!'
line3 = 'Spam!'

>>> wspace(line1)
True
>>> wspace(line2)
True
>>> wspace(line3)
False

>>> whitespace
'\t\n\x0b\x0c\r '
```

Hopefully this suffices without explanation.

Answer (score 3):

Basically the same as Alexander's answer, but expressed as a one liner without a regex.

```
from string import whitespace

if line.startswith(tuple(w for w in whitespace)): 
    outFile.write(line);
```

Answer (score 2):

> whether a line starts with a word or tab or white space in python

```
if re.match(r'[^ \t].*', line):
     print "line starts with word"
```

Answer (score 2):

Yet another approach to match any whitespace character:

```py
if line[:1].isspace():
```

Comment: you may need length check

Comment: @w..k It will return `False` if the line is empty